# Something is interfering with my WiFi connection on my laptop. Is it the dedicated GPU?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, interference

This is my second time trying to narrow down the issue.

##### I live in rental place (house bottom floor) my landlord lives above me and has the WiFi router up there.

Laptop specs:

- It's a gaming laptop AORUS 7KB
- CPU Intel Core i7-10750H @ 2.6GHz
- OS Windows 11 Latest update (with copilot), but same issue was in previous version of win 11
- RAM 16GB
- GPU RTX 2060 and also Integrated Intel UHD Graphics
- 2 SSD's 512GB SX8200PNP-512GT-S (original) and 1TB Crucial CT1000P1SSD8 (added myself)

Router specs:

- Telenor 1091bla
- **Protocol**: Wi-Fi 5 (802.11ac)
- **Security type**: WPA2-Personal
- **Manufacturer**: Intel Corporation
- **Description**: Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
- **Driver version**: 22.20.0.6
- **Network band**: 5 GHz
- **Network channel**: 104
- **Link speed (Receive/Transmit)**: 650/468 (Mbps)

Telenor1091bla Protocol: Wi-Fi 5 (802.11ac) Security type: WPA2-Personal Manufacturer: Intel Corporation Description: Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz Driver version: 22.20.0.6 Network band: 5 GHz Network channel: 104 Link speed (Receive/Transmit): 650/468 (Mbps)

Before we go down I just want to tell you how I measure slow downs.

I use `ping google.com -t` and watch for ping usually I get it 16ms if everything is normal.

So far what I've discovered is that when my laptop is plugged in and my dedicated GPU doesn't perform any heavy work WiFi works fine.

But when I open any game that requires some heavier GPU work (like Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020) my ping jumps up to 1000ms and more then eventually I get request time out.

Now if I unplug the charger while the game is running the ping immediately goes back to 16ms and it doesn't even fluctuate, 99% of the time the ping comes back 16ms.

##### Few more things that I noticed:

- I tried to share my mobile internet from my phone to my laptop via android hotspot and both times while plugged in and unplugged it worked fine while game was on.
- I tried over LAN cable didn't have any issues while plugged in and unplugged
- Also, weirdly enough, I tried above actions in a different household and I didn't have any issues with WiFi.

##### My questions:

- Can this be an issue with the WiFi router and something in my laptop not being compatible hence the interference?
- Is there anything I can do to further investigate and find the culprit?
- And obvious one how to fix it?

Comment: What is the router's model? Telenor seems to relate more to software than routers.

Comment: @harrymc Im not sure whats the routers model since my landlord has it he lives above me

Comment: One idea may be that your laptop power supply is not strong enough to support the GPU when it's going full speed. The RTX 2060 is rated 160 W maximum. Try to calculate your needs with the [newegg power calculator](https://www.newegg.com/tools/power-supply-calculator)

Comment: @harrymc hmm, but this is original adapter although i bought it in Australia so it has Australian wall socket plug, but im in europe now so i have to use AU to EU adapter to plug it into EU wall, but i did the same thing in UK and here in my aunts house and i didn't have any issues seems to be the problem only in my current house

Comment: Perhaps try to isolate the problem by trying other power sockets in your house.

Comment: @harrymc also i have RTX 2060 Mobile (laptop version) which is rated 115W maximum https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2060-mobile.c3348

Comment: @harrymc I tried every socket in the house same problem on all of them

Comment: If it's only something to do with your house or region, there isn't much advice that I can give beyond trying a UPS.

Comment: @harrymc what is UPS?

Comment: Uninterrupted power supply with a battery. Try to loan one since they aren't cheap and this is only a theory.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems the *power plan* settings need to be changed:

- Plugged in, GPU not heavily laden, WiFi works well, ping = 16 ms
- Heavier GPU work ping jumps up to 1 second
- *Charger unplugged* while running game is running, ping goes back to 16ms

Here are some thing to check in *Power Options*, with the (Windows 10) CPL shown below).

[image: Power Options (Win 10)]

In the *Advanced* settings for *Power Options*, edit the *Active* plan. Look at differences between various settings when *On battery* and when *Plugged in*. For example:

- In *Processor power management*, are any setting set too low when *Plugged in*?
- Is there an issue with *System cooling policy* when *Plugged in*?
- In *Wireless Adapter Settings*, is *Maximum Performance* set for when *Plugged in*?
- In *Graphics Settings*, does **reducing** the GPU performance when *Plugged in* from *Maximum Performance* to *Balanced* or *Maximum battery Life* improve WiFi connectivity? Perhaps the GPU is *also* using so much CPU time that it overloads the system.

Comment: I checked those settings I have done before to, they were set to values as it should be no change. Also in graphics settings I only get to adjust intel's integrated GPU's performance, and its my dedicated GPU RTX 2060 is causing that i suspect. But again as i mentioned it didn't happen in my aunts house, so i start to think its house specific.